# How to extract comma separated result using XPATH

Tags: mysql, xpath

I have the following xml text.

```
<units>
    <unit reference="Ref1" title="Unit 1 Title"></unit>
    <unit reference="Ref2" title="Unit 2 Title"></unit>
</units>
```

I want to read attribute values and produce the output as follows:

```
Ref1-Unit 1 Title,Ref2-Unit 2 Title
```

I am using the following xpath based extractvalue query in mysql to fetch the result:

```
SELECT extractvalue('<units><unit reference="Ref1" title="Unit 1 Title"></unit><unit reference="Ref2" title="Unit 2 Title"></unit></units>', '//unit/@reference | //unit/@title');
```

But this generates the output as follows:

```
Ref1 Unit 1 Title Ref2 Unit 2 Title
```

Comment: don't know about xpath 2, but with xpath 1 you cant do that

Comment: I've done some research and it looks like it is possible with xpath2, but i could not find the solution to my problem, can you help?

Comment: I know nothing about xpath 2.